# SQL - order by 2 columns - order topics ( pinned first, then by created timestamp)

Tags: mysql, forum

I have 1 table topics.

[image: table]

I want to order rows in this way.

first get rows where `pinned = 1` order them by `id ASC`

second will be rows where `pinned = 0` ordered by `created_ts DESC`

code:

```
SELECT topics 
WHERE category_id = :i AND deleted = :d 
ORDER BY pinned ASC, created_ts DESC
```

Note: I switched columns in table by mistake ( edited_by <=> edited_ts )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) to only sort by a column if another column meets certain criterias:

```
SELECT id, title, ...
FROM topics 
WHERE category_id = :i AND deleted = :d 
ORDER BY pinned DESC,   -- first 1 then 0
         CASE WHEN pinned = 1 THEN id ELSE 0 END, -- ignore for pinned=0
         created_ts DESC
```

See [example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23a22e/1).

Comment: Glad I could help. SQL Fiddle is also really useful when providing sample data for questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY pinned DESC,
    CASE WHEN pinned = 1
    THEN id
    ELSE -created_ts
DESC
```

Comment: Did not try it, but are you sure that mixing data-types in the CASE works?

Comment: @PeterLang: no, I'm not. your answer might be better although the `ORDER BY pinned DESC` can be omitted :)

Comment: @PeterLang: default to `-1`? ;)

Comment: I would actually have to default to the maximum value, otherwise `pinned=0` would be before `pinned=1`, right?

Comment: Unless you switch the order of the case statement :)

Comment: Well, I could use `-id` and sort by it `DESC`, but I think it's easier to read this way :)